# JSR82 and Bluetooth dongles

Tags: java, bluetooth, jsr82

I am working in a Windows 7 32 bit computer to develop a java desktop application to communicate with a Bluetooth dongle. I have found a java implementation for the jsr82 API in this link: http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-device-discovery/

The code has no errors and no warnings, but the invocation of the line:

```
LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
```

returns null (so it can not find my Bluetooth device).

Note: The dongle is recognized by the pc.

My question is: What is the way to go when working with java and Bluetooth dongles? Can anyone help me to find a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bluecove as library when working with Bluetooth dongles.